# Объясните смысл конструкции [In, Out] byte[] array

Tags: c#

встретил такую конструкцию в кодяре: [In, Out] byte[] array
Передается как параметр. Дайте пожалуйста четкое конкретно объяснение, зачем оно нужно, почему именно оно применяется, и где почитать подробнее.

Ни в шилде, ни в рихтере, ни в английских/русских артикула, ни на msdn'e я не нашел такого.

Comment: [OutAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute?view=netframework-4.8), [InAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.inattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно параметры с такими атрибутами передаются в неуправляемый код, с дополнительным атрибутом `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]`, на тот случай, когда допустим необходимо получить длину неуправляемого массива первым вызовом *(тогда параметр передается как `null`)*, а перед вторым вызовом. вам необходимо выделить буфер достаточной длины, и после этого передать в данный метод, с ссылкой на длину, т.е. то что вы получили при первом вызове с параметром `null`.

Таким образом, такой массив будет передан как указатель на указтель, и в случае передачи `null`, будет передан `nullptr` *(он же `0` или `IntPtr.Zero`)*.

---

Забыл добавить, что переданная ссылка на массив, будет иметь, или не иметь значения после такого вызова.

Comment: Конкретно `UnmanagedType.LPArray` - это не указатель на указатель, это указатель на первый элемент массива, и длина массива не может меняться. `Out` лишь значит, что массив копируется назад в C#. Чтобы был указатель на указатель, в прототипе вообще должен быть не массив, а ref IntPtr. Различие описано, например, в данной статье: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays